# Is there a way in PHP to data if a name appears in the array already then implode both levels of array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv

The situation I have here is I parse a CSV file with 36269 entries with for example:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Chamberlain | 1000128 |
| Solyeux | 1000129 |
| Estrelaint | 1000134 |
| Chamberlain | 1000136 |
| Estrelaint | 1000140 |

My goal is to have an array as such:

```
$arrayname = 
           [Chamberlain] => [
                         1000128,
                         1000136
                        ] 
           [Solyeux] => [
                        1000129
                        ]       
           [Estrelaint]=> [
                        1000134,
                        1000140
           ]
```

Where if every time it "finds" a key with the matching name it appends data or adds to an array under that name, and then implodes at the end of the CSV to give me a flat array of

```
name => string of ids
```

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
$NameCsv= $this->csv("NameAndID");
$NameArray= [];
foreach ($NameCsv->data as $id => $Names) {
  $Name = $Names['FirstName'];
  $NameArray[$Name][] = $id;
}
$output = implode("\n",$NameArray);
var_dump($output);
```

My CSV parser (first line) gives output as such:

```
{
    "1000128": {
        "id": "1000128",
        "FirstName": "Chamberlain",
    },
    "1000129": {
        "id": "1000129",
        "FirstName": "Solyeux",
    },
    "1000134": {
        "id": "1000134",
        "FirstName": "Estrelaint",
    },
    "1000136": {
        "id": "1000136",
        "FirstName": "Chamberlain",
    },
    "1000140": {
        "id": "1000140",
        "FirstName": "Estrelaint",
    }
...
}
```

I figured the best way I could do it was at the end if I used foreach on the array and imploded that sub-array then another implode $NameArray
example:

```
implode("\n",$NameArray[Chamberlain])
implode("\n",$NameArray[Solyeux])
implode("\n",$NameArray[Estrelaint])
...
$output = implode("\n",$NameArray);

Thank you.
```

Comment: Ok. So what you have you tried? Where are you stuck? What's the specific problem? This is not a free write-my-code service, but we will help you with a specific problem or question about your own attempt to implement your requirement. BTW your title really doesn't make any sense - I think I know what you're saying (probably) but it's pretty confusing. Try to make the title short and snappy, but relevant, and then include more detail in the body of the question (you can use the "edit" button now to change anything you like). There's no requirement to put the full question in the title.

Comment: P.S. as you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: Basically all you have to do in your loop over this data is to add the `id` as a new array element under the `name` key … `$arrayname[$name][] = $id;`

Comment: Sorry, Question has been updated with more information. I think i'm along the lines of what CBroe has just said but unsure best method of "flattening" the arrays